# Phabricator Issue Unhandled Exception ("AphrontQueryException") - #1048: Column 'description' cannot be null

Tags: phabricator

I recently updated Phabricator and when I try to create a new task, I receive the following error:

> Unhandled Exception ("AphrontQueryException") - #1048: Column 'description' cannot be null

It´s important to say that this field isn´t marked as mandatory since this is not a custom field. Also, when I create a task by using another type o form, it works.

Comment: did you run the database update too? after every update you should migrate the database too.

Comment: Yes, I updated it. But regardless, I´ll try it again to see if it will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you updated Phabricator, but didn't fully complete all steps (like updating the database or maybe restarting PHP). See https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/upgrading/